# How to retain query parameters and pass in proxy_pass along with host using a lua block?

Tags: nginx, lua

I have a lua block for populating my backend url according to node env. It forwards the request but drops the query parameters.

```
location / {
set_by_lua_block $url {
if os.getenv("NODE_ENV") == 'prod' then
  return "https://example.com"
else
  return "https://www.com"
}


proxy_pass $url
}
```

Any idea how we can retain the query parameters. My request looks something like this https://newlocation.com/initialize?user=123...

Answer (score 0):

First - ensure you want only `query string`, maybe you also want a `path` to be forwarded.

According [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) there are variables you may use to construct URL while request proxying:

1. [$is_args](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_is_args) - question mark if a request line has arguments, or an empty string otherwise;
2. [$args](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args) - arguments in the request line;
3. [$request_uri](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) - original request uri.

So if you only need a `query string` you should use:

```
proxy_pass $url$is_args$args;
```

And if you also need a `path` you should use:

```
proxy_pass $url$request_uri;
```